# Load the current page via Ajax in php

Tags: php, ajax

I have a problem on my ajax script and I need to load the page without refreshing the page. Base on this code.

index.php

```
<div class="header-page" class="clearfix" role="banner">
        <div class="container">
            <img src="images/logo.png" />
        </div>             
    </div>
    <!-- end of HEADER -->
    <form>
    <div id="contents">
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="container">
            <table id="tableID">
                <tr class="data-head">
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Phase</td>
                    <td>Money 1</td>
                    <td>Money 2</td>
                    <td>Money 3</td>
                </tr>
            <?php   
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
                  $id = $row[0];
                  $companyname = $row[1];
                  $client = $row[2];
                  $package = $row[3];
                  $payment1 = $row[4];
                  $payment2 = $row[5];
                  $payment3 = $row[6];


                  echo '<tr id="'.$id.'">';
                  echo '<td><b>'.$client.'</b></td>';
                  echo '<td>';
                  echo '<select class="phase" onchange="trackPhases(this.value)">';        
                           if($phase_status=='Design'){
                            echo '<option value="'.$phase_status.''.$id.'" selected>'.$phase_status.'</option>';
                            echo '<option value="Build-Out'.$id.'">Build-Out</option>';
                            echo '<option value="Launch'.$id.'">Launch</option>';
                           }
                           if($phase_status=='Build-Out'){
                            echo '<option value="Design'.$id.'">Design</option>';
                            echo '<option value="'.$phase_status.''.$id.'" selected>'.$phase_status.'</option>';
                            echo '<option value="Launch'.$id.'">Launch</option>';
                           }
                           if($phase_status=='Launch'){
                            echo '<option value="Design'.$id.'">Design</option>';
                            echo '<option value="Build-Out'.$id.'">Build-Out</option>';
                            echo '<option value="'.$phase_status.''.$id.'" selected>'.$phase_status.'</option>';
                           }
                  echo  '</select>';
                  echo  '</td>';
                  echo '</tr>';
                }
            ?>  
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="txtHint"></div>
```

And this is my Ajax script. I created a dropdown control(just a sample) on the html table code. When I select a value on the dropdown -- `select class="phase" onchange="trackPhases(this.value)`, it should automatically load the page via Ajax not a refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackPhases(str)
    {
        if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
    else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }


    xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

My index.php is fine though. But there is something wrong with my Ajax script. Please help me.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
  mysql_connect("localhost", "xx", "password");
  mysql_select_db('database');

  $query = "SELECT * FROM project";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  ?>
```

**EDIT**

[image]

**EDIT**
update.php

```
<?php
 mysql_connect("localhost", "xx", "password");
 mysql_select_db('database');

 $query = "SELECT * FROM project";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 $q = $_GET['q'];

 $id = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "",$q);
 $phase_status = preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', $q);

 $sql = 'UPDATE project SET phase_status="'.$phase_status.'" WHERE id = '.$id;

 $retval = mysql_query($sql);
 if(! $retval ){
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: What indication do you have that something is wrong?  In what way is it not working?  By "load the page" do you mean replace all page content, as in the entire document?  If you're doing that anyway, why not just refresh?

Comment: I test the script and its fine. When loading to other page its working. xmlhttp.open("GET","otherpage.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();  -- but If I want to load only the current page. How to do that? because on my current page I have an html table that retrieves all the data on my database. Just a simple ping from a dropdown and It loads using ajax.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  What do you want to do with the response from `otherpage.php`?  Do you want to show that entire page to the user?  Only part of it?  Do you want to replace the current page with it?  Only part of the current page?  Perhaps you can indicate an example in the question with some mocked HTML of what's on the current page, what's on the "other page", and what you want the end result to be?

Comment: where you get $result from ? `while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {`

Comment: Hmmm. I dont want to replace the page. Just only load the index.php page without refreshing the page instead use an ajax script. for example I have a dropdown value, when a user select an item on a dropdown, the page will load automatically but now doing a page refresh but just an ajax.

Comment: Thats a query. I need to load the page so that I am able to retrieve the updated data on my database.

Comment: @Jarich: You're confusing the terminology here.  "Load the page" implies that you want to entirely replace the current page with the new page.  "With AJAX" implies that you want to replace *part* of the current page with *part* of the new page.  You're going to need to demonstrate what you're attempting to do with a small example.

Comment: the important part you allways open the same `DB` without closing them in your index.php .  you allways getting the **same result** , I can not see a `where clause`.

Comment: If you want a ajax get why you comment it ?   `//xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?q="+str,true);
    //xmlhttp.send();`

Comment: I added now screenshot and the where clause on the question. For example on the first dropdown. 'Launch' item, if i will select the 'launch' item, the whole page will load(Not a refresh).

Comment: I also can not see in your index.php where you handle : `index.php?q="+str` a code part in your index.php `if (isset($_GET['q'])) { ` would be good.

Comment: @moskito-x , the //xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?q="+str,true); //xmlhttp.send(); is actually xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?q="+str,true); xmlhttp.send();--- which updates the dropdown value. via ajax. Its working though because I only updated the value from my dropdown.

Comment: Why you give us not actuall code ??

Comment: The above code (EDIT)'update.php' is my code. All I want to do is to  to load the current page using. I already loaded a different page. using this line. <div id="txtHint"></div>

Comment: We can not see where you call `xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?q="+str,true);` in your code !!!

Comment: The above code. I updated it. EDIT update.php

Comment: NO , we must see this in your index.php in `function trackPhases(str)` .

Comment: Yes. Its already there.

Comment: Now you put it in, it's there ;-)

Comment: Have you seen my updated answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say it only to notice .

**Please use `PDO` or `mysqli` **

my using of `mysql_query()` is only to fit your code

---

If the code of update.php you give us is like we can see .

You can not get a response that you can replace, when you send no output !

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function trackPhases(str)
{
....
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
  }
....

xmlhttp.open("GET","update.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

update.php

```
.... 
$sql = 'UPDATE project SET phase_status="'.$phase_status.'" WHERE id = '.$id;

 $retval = mysql_query($sql);
 if(! $retval ){
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
 }
```

The only output you will get is when there is an error :

output :

```
'Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
```

and immediately terminate your script ..

So your question `Load the current page via Ajax in php` has nothing to do with what you want to get .

you want to replace the whole

```
<table id="tableID">
....
<?php   
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
....
</table>
```

with the **new** content from your `table: project` .

---

**Only a Tip :**

You can put above

```
<table id="tableID">
....
<?php   
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
....
</table>
```

code in a extra include `setSelect.php` with a function

```
<?php 
function getSelect($result) {
?>
   <table id="tableID">
   ....
<?php   
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
?>
   </table> 
}
```

in index.php your code becomes

```
<?php
include "setSelect.php";
....
?>
<div class="main-container">
    <div id="newCont" class="container">
       <?php  getSelect($result); ?>
    </div>
</div>

....
?>
```

update.php

```
<?php
include "setSelect.php";
 .... 
 $sql = 'UPDATE project SET phase_status="'.$phase_status.'" WHERE id = '.$id;

 $retval = mysql_query($sql);
 if(! $retval ){
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $query = "SELECT * FROM project";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if ($result) {
  getSelect($result);
 }
?>
```

Now you have to change your `getElementById()` to

```
document.getElementById("newCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

to match the new created container `id` .

I'm shure you know what i mean.